# Can (or should) data dominated by two values be treated as categorical?

Tags: categorical-data, paired-data, numerics

**Problem.** I have few data sets containing real values (*aka* observation and prediction). >85% of data values are oscillating between two values exactly (e.g. 0 or 10), while the rest are real numbers in between (thus, it is dominated by only 2 states). I am planning to choose a method to calculate similarity (e.g. pair t-test or McNemar's test).

**Question**: Could or should this data be treated as numerical? Or, is more appropriate to treat it as categorical?

Comment: What does this variable **represent** in real life?  That might be important for your decision ...

Comment: It might be possible to do both, e.g., using a zero/one inflated model that models the probability of 0/between/10 and then models the relationship between the predictor and outcome for the %15 in between. A nice blog post about this [here](https://www.robertkubinec.com/post/limited_dvs/).

Answer (score 1):

The short answer is that there's nothing *wrong* with doing this per se, and it can be useful when your raw data isn't appropriate for something like a t-test. Coding the data as above or below $5$ is probably the most sensible approach in your example.

However, doing this slightly changes the nature of the questions you're asking of your data, and throws away some information that might be worth trying to capture with a more sophisticated model fit to continuous data, so ultimately you have to exercise judgement.

Comment: Thank you all for your inputs. If it helps, the nature of the data is just intensity of a process; intensity values have lower and upper bounds as was mentioned.

Comment: Are these bounds inherent bounds on the process, or in some sense bounds imposed after the fact?

Comment: inherited boundary condition for that process.